# What does block the crawl of my website by Httrack or Wget?

Tags: wget, httrack

I am attempting to clone my website to show it for a presentation offline. However I tried either with Httrack either with Wget and both are stoping to the second level of the source tree. What could be the reason ?

This is the Wget cmd : `wget -r -linf -k -p -E robots=off http://ouistipix.com/`

And this is for Httrack : `httrack http://ouistipix.com/` [(default)](https://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html)

Any idea of what I am doing wrong ? Or what could block further crawl ?

If this can help this is the log of Httrack :

```
HTTrack3.48-21 launched on Mon, 30 May 2016 23:00:45 at http://ouistipix.com/
(httrack http://ouistipix.com/ )

Information, Warnings and Errors reported for this mirror:
note:   the hts-log.txt file, and hts-cache folder, may contain sensitive information,
    such as username/password authentication for websites mirrored in this project
    do not share these files/folders if you want these information to remain private

    23:00:45    Warning:    HTML file (15910 bytes) retransferred due to lack of cache: ouistipix.com/
    23:01:12    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/js/jquery/jquery.easing.1.3.js, 'ouistipix.com/js/jquery/jquery.easing.1.3.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:12    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/js/tools.js, 'ouistipix.com/js/tools.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:12    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/js/jquery/jquery.autocomplete.js, 'ouistipix.com/js/jquery/jquery.autocomplete.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:12    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/global.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/global.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:12    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockpermanentlinks/blockpermanentlinks.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockpermanentlinks/blockpermanentlinks.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:12    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockviewed/blockviewed.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockviewed/blockviewed.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:12    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockmyaccount/blockmyaccount.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockmyaccount/blockmyaccount.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:13    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/editorial/editorial.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/editorial/editorial.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:13    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blocknewproducts/blocknewproducts.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blocknewproducts/blocknewproducts.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:13    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockuserinfo/blockuserinfo.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockuserinfo/blockuserinfo.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:13    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blocklanguages/blocklanguages.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blocklanguages/blocklanguages.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:14    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockmanufacturer/blockmanufacturer.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockmanufacturer/blockmanufacturer.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:14    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockcms/blockcms.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockcms/blockcms.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:14    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blocktags/blocktags.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blocktags/blocktags.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:14    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockstore/blockstore.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockstore/blockstore.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:14    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/css/jquery.autocomplete.css, 'ouistipix.com/css/jquery.autocomplete.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:14    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/product_list.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/product_list.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:14    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blocksearch/blocksearch.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blocksearch/blocksearch.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:15    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockcategories/blockcategories.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockcategories/blockcategories.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:15    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blocknewsletter/blocknewsletter.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blocknewsletter/blocknewsletter.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:15    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/js/tinydropdown2/tinydropdown.js (from ouistipix.com/)
    23:01:15    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/js/tinydropdown2/tinydropdown.css (from ouistipix.com/)
    23:01:24    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/css/jquery.cluetip.css, 'ouistipix.com/css/jquery.cluetip.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:24    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/scenes.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/scenes.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:24    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/img/c/6.jpg, 'ouistipix.com/img/c/6.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:24    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/img/c/8.jpg, 'ouistipix.com/img/c/8.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:25    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/img/c/32.jpg, 'ouistipix.com/img/c/32.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:25    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/cms.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/cms.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:26    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/logiciel.jpg, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/logiciel.html' could not be found on disk
    23:01:32    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/img/c/7.jpg, 'ouistipix.com/img/c/7.html' could not be found on disk
    23:03:29    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/img/c/12.jpg, 'ouistipix.com/img/c/12.html' could not be found on disk
    23:03:29    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/img/c/9.jpg, 'ouistipix.com/img/c/9.html' could not be found on disk
    23:03:32    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/sitemap.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/sitemap.html' could not be found on disk
    23:03:33    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/contact-form.css, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/contact-form.html' could not be found on disk
    23:03:34    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/font/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.woff, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/font/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.html' could not be found on disk
    23:03:40    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/font/MYRIADPRO-COND.woff, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/font/MYRIADPRO-COND.html' could not be found on disk
    23:03:44    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/font/MYRIADPRO-SEMIBOLDIT.woff, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/font/MYRIADPRO-SEMIBOLDIT.html' could not be found on disk
    23:03:50    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/font/MYRIADPRO-SEMIBOLD.woff, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/font/MYRIADPRO-SEMIBOLD.html' could not be found on disk
    23:03:55    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/font/MYRIADPRO-CONDIT.woff, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/font/MYRIADPRO-CONDIT.html' could not be found on disk
    23:04:00    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/font/MYRIADPRO-BOLDIT.woff, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/font/MYRIADPRO-BOLDIT.html' could not be found on disk
    23:04:06    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/font/MYRIADPRO-BOLDCONDIT.woff, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/font/MYRIADPRO-BOLDCONDIT.html' could not be found on disk
    23:04:11    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/font/MYRIADPRO-BOLDCOND.woff, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/font/MYRIADPRO-BOLDCOND.html' could not be found on disk
    23:04:17    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/font/MYRIADPRO-BOLD.woff, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/font/MYRIADPRO-BOLD.html' could not be found on disk
    23:04:21    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/icon/sitemap.gif (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockpermanentlinks/blockpermanentlinks.css)
    23:04:21    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/icon/contact.gif (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockpermanentlinks/blockpermanentlinks.css)
    23:04:21    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/icon/star.gif (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockpermanentlinks/blockpermanentlinks.css)
    23:04:21    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/block_footer_myaccount.jpg (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockmyaccount/blockmyaccount.css)
    23:04:21    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/block_header_myaccount.jpg (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockmyaccount/blockmyaccount.css)
    23:04:21    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/bullet_myaccount.gif (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockmyaccount/blockmyaccount.css)
    23:04:21    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/block_bg_myaccount.jpg (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockmyaccount/blockmyaccount.css)
    23:04:21    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/icon/cart.gif (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockuserinfo/blockuserinfo.css)
    23:04:21    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/icon/my-account.gif (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockuserinfo/blockuserinfo.css)
    23:04:21    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/v2/produit/fviolet.png, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/v2/produit/fviolet.html' could not be found on disk
    23:04:24    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/block_search_bg.jpg (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blocksearch/blocksearch.css)
    23:04:24    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/icon/search.gif (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blocksearch/blocksearch.css)
    23:04:24    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/icon/less.gif (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockcategories/blockcategories.css)
    23:04:24    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/icon/more.gif (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockcategories/blockcategories.css)
    23:04:24    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/block_footer_page.gif (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockcategories/blockcategories.css)
    23:04:24    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/block_footer_page_footer.png (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockcategories/blockcategories.css)
    23:04:24    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/block_bg.jpg (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/modules/blockcategories/blockcategories.css)
    23:05:01    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/img/loader.gif, 'ouistipix.com/img/loader.html' could not be found on disk
    23:05:01    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/flag_new_bg.jpg (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/scenes.css)
    23:05:01    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/icon/cible.gif (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/scenes.css)
    23:05:01    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/icon/serial_scroll_left.gif (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/scenes.css)
    23:05:01    Error:  "Not Found" (404) at link ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/icon/serial_scroll_right.gif (from ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/css/scenes.css)
    23:05:01    Warning:    Unexpected 412/416 error (Unknown) for ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/version_logiciel.jpg, 'ouistipix.com/themes/ouistipix/img/version_logiciel.html' could not be found on disk
```

Comment: Does it having something to do with file extensions?  It looks like it's looking for `.html` files exclusively

Comment: @Russbear I don't think so there nothing that could point out the need of specification of file in the doc. You can eventually specify but you don't have too. Since I dont specify anything it shall take everything.